# Could not find 'UserSecretsIdAttribute' on assembly but it exists and correct package is added

Tags: asp.net-core, secretsmanager

I follow this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows#access-a-secret

To a .NET Core 3.1 project I've added `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets` package, I have clicked on the project to manage secrets, the file has been created in the `AppData` directory and the `UserSecretsId` has been added automatically in `.csproj` file.
Because the `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` didn't load secrets I decided to add them manually

```
 if (hostContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            builder.AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        }
    })
  .Build();
```

But then I get

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Could not find 'UserSecretsIdAttribute' on assembly 'XXX'.
Check that the project for 'XXX' has set the 'UserSecretsId' build property.
If the 'UserSecretsId' property is already set then add a reference to the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets package.
  Source=Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets
```

I've checked the suggestion in the expecion's description and both predicaments are fulfilled.

Answer (score 10):

Same issue here. after check the source code in GitHub
https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/f64994e0655659faefccead7ccb5c1edbfd4d4ba/src/Config.UserSecrets/UserSecretsConfigurationExtensions.cs#L94

Check if you have `<GenerateAssemblyInfo>true</GenerateAssemblyInfo>` in your .csproj file as well.

Comment: I used shared assembly that why I need to add this parameter it manually in the code(runtime) and at project level(compile time for VS).

Comment: var attribute = assembly.GetCustomAttribute<UserSecretsIdAttribute>(); won't able to get the UserSecretsId in .csproj if GenerateAssemblyInfo is set to false. try debug this code

Comment: @Yoda I'm having the same issue (i.e., CreateDefaultBuilder is not adding secrets.json to config provider, ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is Development, and the UseSecretsId is in the .csproj file) and I also have SharedAssemblyInfo.cs.  How did you add the UserSecretsId to the SharedAssemblyInfo.cs file?

Comment: @Mike I haven't you need usersecretsID in the csproj(for Visual Studio) and in the startup class as an annotation(for runtime). Then it will work.

Comment: @Yoda Thanks for the response!  I'm not following, what are you referring to when you say "in the startup class as an annotation"?  Could you provide a code snippet?  Thanks again.

Comment: @Mike. You can add it in startup class or SharedAssemblyInfo.cs `[assembly: UserSecretsId("XXXguidXXX")]`

Comment: @Yoda Adding it to SharedAssemblyInfo.cs did the trick, thanks again!

Comment: @Mike. Upvote question if you may, thanks.

Comment: @Yoda - I had the same issue and fixed in the same way.  Took me hours to find this answer.  Thanks so much for the solution!

Answer (score 8):

Faced the same runtime error. I have disabled the automatic creation of the `AssemblyInfo` for assembly in the `csproj`, because my system CI automatically updates this file with the version of the build

My fix is to add

```
[assembly: UserSecretsId ("<Project guid>")]
```

in `AssemblyInfo`.

Comment: I had the same issue. At the beginning, the AssemblyInfo was generated automatically so everything worked fine. Then suddenly I need to set <GenerateAssemblyInfo> to false and things fell in parts. Took me hours to found out that. Who knows modifying assembly info can break secrets.json huh?

Comment: This solution also worked for me in .NET Framework 4.8 project

Comment: I just bashed my head in for hours trying to get a .Net Framework 4.8 Console Application to load my UserSecrets. This was the solution. Though in my case I had GenerateAssemblyInfo set to true. I also used my own UserSecretsId instead of the Project GUID.

Answer (score 4):

You should have the UserSecretsId listed in your .csproj file. If you right click on the API layer and manage user secrets confirm that the GUID matches in the AppData directory with whats in the project.

```
<PropertyGroup>
<UserSecretsId>Your GUID</UserSecretsId>
```

Your Program.cs class should be using the CreateDefaultBuilder, you should see that there is a section to include Secrets when the environment is Development. Check your ASP  `"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"` is set to development. Lastly I'm assuming your executing assembly has the PropertyGroup for the user secrets mentioned above.

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

Comment: Everything that you've provided is already done. However I have SharedAssemblyInfo.cs in the project Properties and if I put the id there it will be loaded during runtime however VS needs it also in csproj to be aware of secrets file. It's weird.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the context menu on your project and choose "Manage User Secrets..." and save the empty user secrets configuration file. Visual Studio should create the necessary project file entries automatically.

Comment: I was going to do just that, but for some reason Visual Studio failed to include that option in the context menu. It was also hidden from the Project menu. At which point I starting searching the internet and wound up here.

Answer (score 0):

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Could not find 'UserSecretsIdAttribute' on assembly ''.
Check that the project for '' has set the 'UserSecretsId' build property.
If the 'UserSecretsId' property is already set then add a reference to the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets package.'

Adding this package solved the issue.
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).